# Need to leave WordPress as blog is growing; what CMS could I use?

Tags: web-development, cms

I am mainly a Java developer (with an old and decaying PHP background) and run an association a blog/website with a growing and fair amount of content/visits/community.

It started as a WordPress and WordPress has been wonderful at start; but as years passes we struggle more and more each time we want to add features or modify those we have.

Also, it become for me a real pain in the **s to do anything with the WordPress PHP code. I think because I began to become allergic to PHP due to my daily Java work; but more so to the WordPress code witch seems to me like gigantic crappy (but working) contraption.

So the blog need to move more and more from a blog to a more complete website / community and I decided we needed to change.

Just to give an idea of actual used/wanted features:

- forum
- user profiles
- nice category/menus/stuff management
- ads
- picture galleries

The main desirable feature would be the ability to easily and cleanly add features (either through plugins, development, or whatever).

Given that background, would you have any recommendations?

I thought of Drupal witch seems much more clean, and that's my only idea for now. I would love a Java CMS, but I'm unsure what exists outside PHP (or Ruby/Python) in CMS world.

So I guess I'm just looking for inputs of any kind here as I feel a bit lost.

Comment: Who adds pages and features on your website? Only an admin, or a team? Or each user can add the widgets they want?

Comment: Take a look at eXo Platform. Exo is an open source, CMS/Collaboration Platform written in Java.

Comment: What kind of features are you trying to add. Both Drupal and WordPress have a lot of Modules or Plugins. I generally prefer Drupal, but for blogs I actually think WordPress is better.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what [Liferay](http://liferay.com/) was created for.

- Web content management: Add/manage sites and pages, like any other CMS
- Written in Java
- Easily drag-and-drop widgets (forums/polls/files repositories/pictures/ads/chat/workflows/themes/etc) from the [Liferay Marketplace](https://web.liferay.com/marketplace)
- Very clean way to extend it, via portlets, or via Liferay extension points for heavy-weight modifications. All in Java/JSP.

Liferay is free and open source.